# How to create this url in java

Tags: java, string, url

I have this url to create in java. The parameters base-url,  US, and test will come from config file, while part1 and part2 will be variables in the program. So the skeleton is something like.

https://base-url/search/part1/part2?region=US&env=test

Currently i am using an inefficient way to create this url using strings concatenations

```
   AppConfig.findString(baseurlstring) + "/search/" + part1 + "/" 
             + part2 + "?region=" + AppConfig.findString(regionString) 
             + "&env=" + AppConfig.findString(envString);
```

Is there a more efficient to do it using the URL class, and then convert it to a string?

Comment: use the StringBuilder class?

Comment: Theres a dedicated URL class in Java for creating urls. I am sure there is a better way to creating urls then just building strings.

Comment: You could start with simple `String` with placeholders; `https://base-url/search/{p1}/{p2}?region={p3}&env={p4}` and then replace the parameters with values.  I'd probably make a factory class which took the parameters, worked the magic and returned a `URL`

Comment: Did you see the URL class javadocs? There is not much more you can do with it. I would use StringBuilder or String.format()

Comment: If you're using Spring, the built-in `UriTemplate` is your friend. If not, there are [other implementations](https://github.com/damnhandy/Handy-URI-Templates) that will make your life simpler.

Comment: Really?The URL class does not provide anyway to create an object from the above string url?

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` is the way to code in this case.
For example:

`StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()`

Any time you want to build or add to the URL,

For example, use: `builder.append(AppConfig.findString(regionString))`

In the end you reach the URL you want to build by calling `append()` repeatedly.

Now the reason to do this, is because `StringBuilder` is faster than `StringBuffer` but as a caveat it is non-synchronous (not thread safe).

Read the [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` is one way but it still results in rather verbose code.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(AppConfig.findString(baseurlstring))
   .append("/search/")
   .append(part1)
   .append("/")
   .append(part2)
   .append("?region=")
   .append(AppConfig.findString(regionString))
   .append("&env=")
   .append(AppConfig.findString(envString));
```

Another way is to use a `java.lang.String::format()` as in

```
String fmt = "https://%s/search/%s/%s?region=%s&env=%s");
...
String url = String.format(fmt,
    AppConfig.findString(baseurlstring),
    part1, 
    part2
    AppConfig.findString(regionString),
    AppConfig.findString(envString));
```

This method is known to be slower than using `StringBuilder` but unless you're doing hundreds of thousands of these the time difference will be on the order of milliseconds.